# tips to delete huge - extremely huge no.of millions

Tags: ufs

I have around six million files (only files ,no sub-dir) to delete in UFS file system.
Any tips to increase the performance?

Comment: You're pretty much stuck waiting it out. It's going to take a good long time too.

Comment: you  could always put the command into back ground with & , so you can do other work while you delete files. You could always just recreate the file system with mkfs /dev/mydevice, this would be faster than deleting files, although you will loose everything on that file system.

Answer (score 2):

Not for this time but in the future would it be possible for you to create them in a separate file system? this would at least give you the option of just wiping the whole FS if that were appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Get the file names with `ls -f` or `ls -U` (if supported) to avoid having `ls` or your shell sort out the names.  Just `ls -f | egrep -v '\.|\.\.' | xargs rm -f`.  If this is a frequent necessity, you might want to write a small C utility to do it.

Comment: That skips *any* file with a dot in its name, perhaps you meant `egrep -v '^\.$|^\.\.$'`

Comment: @Dennis Williamson - you're right.  Though if the million files have generated names, it's likely that none start with dot.

Comment: Your grep is intended to eliminate the directories `.` and `..` from the output of `ls`, but it will also eliminate such generated filenames as `tmp.C9rDc96tca`

Answer (score 0):

find /mydir -type f -exec rm {} \;